# Android proto import files

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I am making a Flutter android application which uses photo files. First I had all definitions based in one .proto file. But now I had to split the definitions onto multiple files.

With one file my build script worked:

```
buildscript {
    ...

    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.17'
    }
}
...
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        main.proto.srcDirs += '../../protos'
    }

    ...
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        if (project.hasProperty('protoc_platform')) {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.18.0:${protoc_platform}"
        } else {
            artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.18.0"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option "lite"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the folder structure

```
project
  | - android app
    | - android
       |- build.gradle 
  | - protos
      myfile.proto
```

Now I have updated it to

```
project
  | - android app
    | - android
       |- build.gradle 
  | - protos
      |- shared
         |- dependency 
          - dependency.proto
      - myfile.proto
```

myfile.proto imports dependency.proto, but when I compile the android project I get the error that protos/shared/dependency/dependency.proto is not found.

How must I update the build.gradle file?

Comment: I don't use Java|Gradle but I'm familiar with protocol buffers. The compiler (`protoc`) is very particular about paths to proto source folders. In this case, you appear to only have a single source folder (`protos`) and so this can remain unchanged (I think `protoc`'s `--proto_path` corresponds to `main.proto.srcDirs` in Gradle). The second aspect is that the protobuf file imports must be absolute (!) references to these imports paths and this structure must be reflected by `package` naming.

Comment: In your case, `myfile.proto`  has no (!) `package` and must `import "shared/dependency/dependency.proto`. `dependency.proto` must have a package reference `package shared.dependency;` to reflect its location correctly in the protobuf package hierarchy and, references to its Messages must be `shared.dependency.{X}`.

Comment: the protobufs compile for go and swift, but somehow not for android @DazWilkin so I don't think it has something to do with the .proto files

Comment: Yes, that wasn't stated in your question but it's an accurate conclusion.